# how to get tab match in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have the content.

```
        Welcome     to      the     world.
```

I want to get \t match count from starting point. Not inside the content tab.

i tried this but not work. It get all the tab count.

```
 use strict;
    use warnings FATAL => 'all'; 
    my $cnt = qq(           welcome     to      the     world);

    my $number = () = $cnt =~ /(\t)/gi;
    print join("\n", $number);exit;
```

Thanks advance. please any one help.

Comment: What value do you expect to be printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the match count of the tab characters from the start of the string.

```
my $number = () = $cnt =~ /\G\t/g;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can solve the problem by anchoring with `\G`

```
my $number = () = $cnt =~ /\G\t/g;
```

But it would be far more efficient to use

```
$cnt =~ /^\t*/;
my $number = $+[0];
```

Comment: (+1) for the more effecient way.